Equivalence between OpenTelemetry and Prometheus metrics
I'm leveraging OpenTelemetry metrics on a k8s environment.
Metrics are sent to a Prometheus instance and consumed by Grafana.
I'm trying set up k8s infra dashboards leveraging existing ones found on Grafana or Github.
As advised here, I've configured the collectors to pull metrics about the k8s infrastructure using the following receivers:

kubeletstats
hostmetrics
k8s_cluster

I was expecting Otel metrics to be somehow equivalent to the ones provided by Prometheus, possibly with some name changes, as hinted here).
Yet I see that:

names are substantially different
some metrics simply do not seem to be available in OpenTelemetry, even under different names (could not find the Otel equivalent of kube_node_info, which I use to count the nodes)
some metrics are often aggregated across multiple nodes/pods
there is no description for metrics coming from OpenTelemetry
some of the Prometheus metrics are shaded by Otel and vice versa

I've also tried using both OTLP and Prometheus exporters and adding attributes processor, but none of that solves the fundamental issue.
Can anyone help me understand:

why the two projects are not aligned in terms of metrics (even just semantically)
what can be done to use Grafana/Prometheus dashboards with Otel metrics


You should consider moving these questions to the appropriate OTEL repos. The community here can't answer them, most likely.
